# What is required in order for Standby to be available under Windows XP Pro?

Tags: windows-xp, power-management, standby

My laptop just had its motherboard replaced by the IT department at work. Since then, the Standby facility has disappeared from my computer. As far as I can tell, all drivers for the new motherboard are installed correctly. What else do I need to do to get the Standby option back? What might be causing it to be unavailable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This computer died again very soon after this question was asked, and was replaced completely on this occasion. So unfortunately, this issue was never resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the display drivers usually fixes this problem, although you may also want to check out [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;330638&Product=winxp) Microsoft KB article.

Comment: I have tried to install the latest Intel GMA drivers, but they refuse to install since it's a Dell laptop. The system's already running the latest Intel driver released by Dell, but I will try reinstalling.

Comment: run the driver as administrator

Comment: +10000 I just had this same problem after swapping video cards. Reinstalling the drivers put Standby back in my shutdown menu on the next reboot.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above 2 responses, please also ensure that you have got appropriate Administrative rights on the Laptop to make the necessary registry changes.  Otherwise, you would require to go back to the IT Department to fix this problem.  Hoping to see the right solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to find out what Motherboard you have? This can be done with [SiSoft's Sandra](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/index.html?dir=dload&location=sware_dl_3264&langx=en&a=)

Then we can find out whether it might be a bios setting that disables standby. You could off course search your bios yourself to find this out.

Comment: I think the file block problem only relates to Hibernate. I am not too fussed about Hibernate, but would definitely like Standby working again. I think I will have to check all the BIOS settings on this new motherboard in case they set something strangely.

Comment: I was sort of assuming you were referring to hibernate with standby, let me see if I can find another solution